# javacpp.jar - No native JavaCPP library in memory

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I'm trying to run this line: 
`BytePointer bP = new BytePointer(imageSource);`

Where the `imageSource` is an array of byte. I get the following error in console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/facerecognition] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: No native JavaCPP library in memory. (Has Loader.load() been called?)] with root cause
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.googlecode.javacpp.BytePointer.allocateArray(I)V
```

Important note:

- yesterday was working fine, today "BOOM" (no idea)
- the library `javacpp.jar` is correctly added in build path
- I'm using `openCV 248`
- this Dynamic Java Project is running under Tomcat 7.0.47
- the only thing changed between yesterday and today is the RAM upgrade (from 4 to 8 GB)

I have totally no idea what is happening.

Comment: Perhaps your PATH variable was reset when you upgraded your RAM?

Comment: Is that possible? I mean: eclipse does not handle situation like this?  My last chance will be to destroy this project and create new one, with a new path ecc...
Meanwhile I'm waiting other suggestions

Comment: What platform are you on? How are you launching Tomcat?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 64 bit (Professional). Tomcat is correctly added as server in eclipse, then I added my web project on it and then I launch tomcat. As I said, everything was working 2 days ago

Comment: created new project, different workspace, re-download opencv and changed path system variable. Nothing to do, same error.
I give up, I'll change my thesis. Thanks to all

Comment: Where is the JavaCPP dll located? I'm sure you have made sure that it is in one of the directories in your PATH variable, right?

Comment: Exactly! Path variable is ok, just followed this tutorial http://opencvlover.blogspot.it/2012/04/javacv-setup-with-eclipse-on-windows-7.html (same approach for other tutorials)

Comment: You might be hitting a corner case. Have you tried to call `Loader.load()` manually?